# how to find inverse of a number in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Am new to ruby.
Can any one tell me how to find inverse of a number in ruby.Is there any function for it?
or just 1/number ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume from your example that you mean the multiplicative inverse, normally called the reciprocal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use floating point numbers:

```
1.0 / number
```

If you use `1 / number`, and number is the integer 5, you'll just get 0 instead of 0.2.

Answer (score 3):

Although not exactly an answer to your question, I think we should mention here [Rational](http://apidock.com/ruby/Rational) class, suitable for keeping rational numbers without the loss implied with storage of float-point numbers, i.e. in form of fractions:

```
n = 3
#=> 3
r = Rational(1,3)
#=> 13 # don't let this confuse you, this is 1/3 in fact
r.to_s
#=> "1/3"
```

You can perform usual rational arithmetic on such numbers, keeping the fractions' accuracy:

```
r = r * r
#=> 19
r.to_s
#=> "1/9"
```

And, eventually, you can convert these numbers to ordinary floats:

```
r.to_f
#=> 0.111111111111111
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use something different like:

```
number**(-1)
```

that is the same as

```
1.0/number
```

Comment: I like this more. It's more semantic than the arbitrary adding of `.0` to make it use floating point arithmetic. Nice idea.

Answer (score 0):

If your number is Rational then you can use the component parts to create the inverse Rational value:

```
@rational = Rational(1,27)
@inverse = Rational(@rational.denominator, @rational.numerator)
```

Oddly Rational doesn't have an inverse function.